# Any way to save Date type as local time in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

It seems like all the date type in Mongo DB are saved as UTC time. Is there anyway to configure from the MongoDB server side that I can change the default date type to display as local time? For example, to display/save as CTC time on the DB? Thanks,

Comment: I just save everything as UTC and then convert it to local time when I put it into reports or surface data on my website.  You can convert it when you load it - I have a module in Python that does it ... how are you loading your data to mongo?

Comment: The data is loaded by the Java developers as local time, once it is entered to the DB, it saved automatically as UTC time. I am running a report need to filter it as local time, how do I do the convert just using Mongo DB query? For example I want to retrieve data for the past 5 days, I can use aggregate function $match: { "CreateDate":  { $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-5)), $lte: new Date()}}}. But the display is the UTC time and I think the time range is also UTC right?

Comment: your date object should look like: 2020-11-22T20:07:32.600+00:00 and the +00:00 is what makes it UTC.  If the dates are being input in local time, that would be something like -08:00 (PT).  If the javascript is collecting the data as local, but not adjusting the TZ in the ISO date format, then you actually have a different problem (sorry) that should get fixed first.  My understanding, Mongo doesn't convert TZ for you, it just inputs what it's told to ...

Comment: This is not supported. MongoDB server operates in UTC only.

Comment: Does your query using `new Date()` return the correct results?

Comment: new Date() still returns the UTC time not the local timezone.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB stores datetime as the number of milliseconds since epoch.  No timezone information is stored with the data.

The value returned by the database would look something like `1614847506286`.

How that is displayed is completely up to the application.

Comment: If I only running mongodb query to create a report not using any other code, how do I convert the UTC time to local time when running the query and how do I convert the UTC time to my local time for the resultset?

Comment: If you are storing the values in MongoDB as date/time types, there will be no need to convert when running the query. (i.e. the number of millliseconds since epoch does not depend on a time zone).  The result set will also contain the date as an integer, choosing a timezone and converting that integer to a date string is up to the client.