# MongoDB database gives me the wrong time from input with type datetime-local

Tags: mongodb, datetime, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodate

When I write a date in my input I receive the wrong time in the database (2 hours earlier than the time I want), in the pictures you can see that I got the hour 5:21 in the database even though I wrote the time 7:21 in the input:

The time in the input:
[image: the time in the input]

The time in the database:

[image: the time in the database]

I thought that it is maybe because of the time zone (I am In Israel) and I try to use the Library `Moment`.

In this way:

```
holiday.beginDate = moment.tz(req.body.beginDate, "Asia/Jerusalem");
```

But, I get the same result.

Someone can tell me what I am doing wrong or what should I do to make the time I write in the input be the same time in the database?

Thank you.

Comment: MongoDB stores all date-times in UTC.  That would be 2 hours behind your local time, rigth?

Comment: Yes, in Israel winter clock is 2 hours differences  and in Israel summer clock is 3 hours differences from UTC

Comment: So if 7:21 is in Israel Time (IST), then the time stored is correct.

Comment: but I need the time to be 7:21 in the database, and it is written as 5:21 there,

Comment: Try `holiday.beginDate = moment.tz(req.body.beginDate, "Asia/Jerusalem").toDate()` and you may need to specify the input format.

Comment: You are telling me that you need to have the wrong time in the database? I sure hope that you’re mistaken there.

Comment: Please see [Any way to save Date type as local time in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66445434/any-way-to-save-date-type-as-local-time-in-mongodb)

Comment: How can I display the time on the client-side as my local time and not UTC? thank you